# How do I prove this cone is open?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $\delta>0$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v\neq 0$.

Define $$U:=\{tv+(1-t)x\in \mathbb{R}^n:t\in[0,1), x\in B(0,\delta)\}$$. Then, how do I prove that $U$ is open?

This seems obvious but I have a trouble actually proving it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @yanko Yes, this is obvious by actually drawing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $u = tv + (1-t)x \in U$. Since $x\in B(0,\delta)$ and $B(0,\delta)$ is open, there is a small enough $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(x, \varepsilon) \subset B(0,\delta)$. And so $tv + B(x,\varepsilon) \subset U$.